# Is there another proof of $V=U+U^\perp$ especially when $V$ is infinite-dimensional?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I'm studying *Linear Algebra Done Right*, the author gave a proof of the theorem(see the figure). However, I personally not quite like the proof, because in a step he use the fact that the projection of $v$ on $U$ is $\langle v,e_1\rangle e_1+\cdots+\langle v,e_m\rangle e_m$. However, this is known by the hindsight. Until the theorem appears, the author didn't(and was unable to) give the proof of this fact. I know that this is rigorous, but I feel that I like the proof without using it. If the vector space $V$ is **finite**-dimensional, I know that there are many proofs of this theorem, and I can give my own one. However, those proofs for finite-dimensional I know, can not be directly extend to the infinite-dimensional case. Are there another proofs for the case $V$ is infinite-dimensional?

[image]

**PS:**  As you might want to know, this is the definition of projection in that book, **after** the theorem.
[image]

Comment: A Hilbert space is a direct sum of a closed subspace and its orthogonal complement.

Comment: @user12580 Sorry, I can't get it. Can you say more?

Comment: The proof is essentially the same as given above.

Comment: What? I'm asking whether there is another proof of it.

Comment: Uh. This is a standard treatment when dealing with a space decomposed into a direct sum.

Comment: Thanks. So theoretically speaking, there can't be another proof that doesn't use the formula $\langle v,e_1\rangle e_1+\cdots+\langle v,e_m\rangle e_m$?

Comment: Many of the standard results for linear algebra don't work for infinite-dimensional vector spaces, at least not without additional analytic and topological (i.e. not purely algebraic) assumptions. This is why the natural context for infinite-dimensional linear algebra is actually functional analysis.

Comment: @ChristianSykes I see. But why can Axler's proof be so easy(although he use the formula $\langle v,e_1\rangle e_1+\cdots+\langle v,e_m\rangle e_m$), and if we don't use this, the proof seems getting more complicated? Is that formula a pretty strong thing far more than we expect at the first glance?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the proof given in Conway's *A Course in Functional Analysis*, 2nd ed. (Theorems 2.5 and 2.6).

> **Step 1:** If $\mathscr{H}$ is a Hilbert space, $K$ a closed, convex subset of $\mathscr{H}$, and $h \in \mathscr{H}$ then there is a unique point $k_0 \in K$ such that $$ \lVert h - k_0 \rVert = \operatorname{dist}(h,K) \equiv \inf \{ \lVert h - k \rVert : k \in K \}. $$

Proof. We start by noting that by translating $K$ to $K - h \equiv \{k - h : k \in K\}$ we may assume $h = 0$. Next, let $d = \operatorname{dist}(0,K)$. Pick some sequence of points $(k_n) \in K$ such that $\lVert k_n \rVert \to d$. We will use convexity to show that $(k_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence and then use the closedness of $K$ to conclude that $k_n \to$ some $k_0 \in K$.

We note that, by [the Parallelogram Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law), $$\left\lVert \frac{k_n - k_m}{2} \right\rVert^2 = \frac{\lVert k_n \rVert^2 + \lVert k_m \rVert^2}{2} - \left\lVert \frac{k_n + k_m}{2} \right\rVert^2. $$
Now, since $K$ is convex, $\frac12 (k_n + k_m) \in K$ (you can also take this as the definition of convexity if you are unfamiliar). Therefore, since $d = \operatorname{dist}(0,K)$, we have $\lVert \frac12 (k_n + k_m) \rVert^2 \ge d^2$.

Now let $N$ be such that $n \ge N$ implies $\lVert k_n \rVert^2 < d^2 + \frac14 \varepsilon^2$. We can do this since $\lVert k_n \rVert \to d$. It follows that

$$ \left\lVert \frac{k_n - k_m}{2} \right\rVert^2 < \frac{2d^2 + \frac{1}{4}\varepsilon^2}{2} - d^2 = \frac14\varepsilon^2. $$

Therefore, $\lVert k_n - k_m \rVert < \varepsilon$. I.e. the sequence $(k_n)$ is Cauchy.

Since $\mathscr{H}$ is complete, and $K$ is closed, there is a limit point $k_0 \in K$ such that $k_n \to k_0$. Since the norm is continuous, $$\lVert k_0 \rVert = \lim_{n \to \infty} \lVert k_n \rVert = d. $$
This shows existence.

For uniqueness, suppose $k_0'$ is a second point in $K$ such that $\lVert k_0' \rVert = d$. Then

$$ d \le \lVert \tfrac12 (k_0 + k_0') \rVert \le \tfrac12 (\lVert k_0 \rVert + \lVert k_0' \rVert) = d. $$
Hence, $\lVert \frac12 (k_0 + k_0') \rVert = d$.

Applying the Parallelogram Law,

$$ \left\lVert \frac{k_0 - k_0'}{2} \right\rVert^2 = \frac{\lVert k_0 \rVert^2 + \lVert k_0' \rVert}{2} - \left\lVert \frac{k_0 + k_0'}{2} \right\rVert^2 = \frac{d^2 + d^2}{2} - d^2 = 0. $$

Therefore $k_0' = k_0$.

> **Step 2**: If $\mathscr{M}$ is a closed linear subspace of $\mathscr{H}$, $h \in \mathscr{H}$ and $f_0 \in \mathscr{M}$ is the unique element such that $\lVert h - f_0 \rVert = \operatorname{dist}(h, \mathscr{M}$ then $h - f_0 \perp \mathscr{M}$. Conversely, if $f_0 \in \mathscr{M}$ is such that $h - f_0 \perp \mathscr{M}$ then $\lVert h - f_0 \rVert = \operatorname{dist}(h, \mathscr{M})$.

Proof. Take $f \in \mathscr{M}$. Then $f_0 + f \in \mathscr{M}$ so we have

$$ d^2 = \lVert h - f_0 \rVert^2 \le \lVert h - (f_0 + f) \rVert^2 = \lVert (h - f_0) - f \rVert^2 = \lVert h - f_0 \rVert^2 - 2\operatorname{Re}\langle h - f_0, f \rangle + \lVert f \rVert^2 $$

whence $2\operatorname{Re}\langle h - f_0, f \rangle \le \lVert f \rVert^2$.

Write $\langle h - f_0, f \rangle = re^{i\theta}$. Replacing $f$ with $te^{i\theta}$ in the preceeding inequality, we have

$$ 2\operatorname{Re}\langle h - f_0, te^{i\theta} f \rangle = 2\operatorname{Re} \Big(te^{-i\theta} \langle h - f_0, f \rangle  \Big) = 2tr \le \lVert te^{i\theta} f\rVert^2 = t^2 \lVert f \rVert^2. $$

Taking $t \to 0$ we see that $r = 0$. I.e. $h - f_0 \perp f$.

For the converse, suppose $f \in \mathscr{M}$, then $f \perp h - f_0$ means that

$$ \lVert h - f \rVert^2 = \lVert (h - f_0) + (f_0 - f) \rVert^2 = \lVert h - f_0 \rVert^2 + \lVert f_0 - f \rVert^2 \ge \lVert h - f_0 \rVert^2. $$

Thus $\lVert h - f_0 \rVert = \operatorname{dist}(h, \mathscr{M})$.

> **Step 3:** Note that this applies when $\mathscr{M}$ is finite dimensional, because finite dimensional subspaces are closed as a consequence of the [Bolzano-Weirstrass Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).